# How to use unapi for biliographic in drupal

Tags: api, drupal-6, citations

I am new to unapi.. can anyone let me know how to use unapi with drupal for biliography. what are the steps to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps described in http://unapi.info/specs/ . It's straightforward. Implementing unAPI in PHP is trivial. You just need to print a citation (BibTeX, etc) for each document.

see also: [Generating bibliographic files (BibTeX, RIS, etc.) from database records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824325/generating-bibliographic-files-bibtex-ris-etc-from-database-records)