# Generating bibliographic files (BibTeX, RIS, etc.) from database records

Tags: mapping, bibliography, citations

Are there methods or tools to facilitate generating bibliographic data files (for BibTeX, EndNote, RefMan, etc.) from database records to show to visitors of a website so they can easily import the citations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A powerful tool to convert between various bibliographic formats is [bibutils](http://sourceforge.net/p/bibutils/home/Bibutils/). EndNote and RefMan should both readily accept the RIS format.

Answer (score 2):

On a Linux system you can execute

```
cat myrisfile.ris | ris2xml | xml2bib > mybibfile.bib
```

to convert myrisfile.ris to mybibfile.bib in a BibTeX format if the package `bibutils` is installed.